# Wordpress edit post sidebar sub-category out of place

Tags: php, wordpress

In the POSTS - CATEGORIES page I have a main category 'Innovation' and a sub category 'Feature'. But for some reason within the edit-post page where you can select the category on the sidebar, the sub category  for Innovation has disconnected itself and is found at the bottom of the list on it's own. Don't see how.

All other categories are fine, even with their own 'Feature' sub category too.

I checked the ID of this sub category and it matches the one found in the main category page. So it's the correct one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably a bug that needs to be raised on the make wordpress core trac. This isn't a question for Stake Overflow per se. indeed not a question at all! ;-)

Comment: If the sub-cat is new try a browser/cache refresh.

Comment: When adding a new post. No issue.  -  
When editing a post already in the feature sub category. No issue.  -  When editing any post in the parent category however, that's when the issue appears.

Answer (score 0):

for getting back your categories perfect selection follow this instruction
1)it happens sometime when you have created new sub categories after creating any post and than you edit existing post that time your categories not coming properly
2)and if you try to Add new Post at that time your all categories position will be fine, check it once
3)for getting your recovery of categories selection, whatever post you have created in that edit it and select whatever categories you want to choose, and than after once click on Update button after that refresh page than after your categories will be coming properly.just now i have done like that...

Once Try it and if answer is helpful than please give correct vote for this..sometime happens for catch problem or other but we cant say exactly whats the issue